# Akka ClusterSingletonProxy to a remote deployed singleton

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I'm trying to send a message to a singleton actor that was deployed on a remote node through another actor.

This is the manager that is waiting for a memberUp event, then deploys `Worker` actor on that node and then sends the singleton a message:

```
object Manager extends App {
  val sys = ActorSystem("mySys", ConfigFactory.load("application").getConfig("manager"))
  sys.actorOf(Props[Manager], "manager")
}

class Manager extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MemberUp(member) if member.address != Cluster(context.system).selfAddress =>
      context.system.actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.props(
        singletonProps = Props(classOf[Worker]),
        singletonName = "worker",
        terminationMessage = End,
        role = Some("worker")).withDeploy(Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(member.address))))

      context.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props(
        singletonPath = s"/user/singleton/worker",
        role = Some(s"worker")), "worker") ! "hello"
  }
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    Cluster(context.system).subscribe(self,classOf[MemberUp])
  }
}
```

This is the worker:

```
object Worker extends App{
  ActorSystem("mySys", ConfigFactory.load("application").getConfig("worker"))
}

class Worker extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg =>
      println(s"GOT MSG : $msg from : ${sender().path.name}")
  }
}
```

And the application.conf:

```
manager {
  akka {
    actor {
      provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }
    cluster {
      auto-down-unreachable-after = 20s
      seed-nodes = [
        "akka.tcp://mySys@127.0.0.1:2552"
      ]
      roles.1 = "manager"

    }
    remote.netty.tcp.port = 2552

  }
}

worker {
  akka {
    cluster {
      auto-down-unreachable-after = 20s
      seed-nodes = [
        "akka.tcp://mySys@127.0.0.1:2552"
      ]
      roles.1 = "worker"
    }
    remote.netty.tcp.port = 2554
    actor {
      provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }
  }
}
```

The worker is initialized (and I can see in the logs the `state change [Start -> Oldest]` message) but the message sent from the manager never arrives to the worker. It used to work fine when I was deploying the singleton on the remote node, but now I want the manager the deploy it.

I also tried to deploy it as the child of the manager (using context instead of context.system) and changed the singleton path to `user/manager/singleton/worker`, but it didn't work.

I'm using Akka 2.3.11

Edit: 
sbt file:

```
name := "MyProject"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
libraryDependencies +=
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.11",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.3.11",
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.0",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % "2.3.11"
```

Comment: Could you please post your build.sbt? It's easier to reproduce without having to search together all the libraries.

Comment: I edited my post with the sbt file

Comment: Thanks, the package for the ClusterSingleton changed in 2.5 and I couldn't figure out, which it was with 2.3.11

Comment: Is there any reason you want to remote deploy the cluster singleton to the worker?

Comment: Not sure what is the question. If you are asking why do I need singleton and not normal actor then its because in my actual application I have another manager and I don't want to restart two workers(I want only one worker in the cluster). If you are asking why won't I just restart the actor from the new process then its because the manager also deploys normal actors so it would be nice to have the logic only in one place- the manager.

Comment: Edited my response, since I got it to work after some trying.

Answer (score 2):

<del>So I played around a bit with different options of creating `ClusterSingletonManager`s and I think deploying them remotely is breaking something within the singleton pattern. I have gathered a few indicators for this:</del>

- <del>Since it is a remote deployment the path of the `ClusterSingletonManager` on the worker node is `/remote/akka.tcp/mySys@127.0.0.1:2552/user/worker`. I don't think the library can / will handle this, since it expects `/user/worker`</del>
- <del>When trying to send the message from the master node using `ClusterSingletonProxy` log in DEBUG mode states `No singleton available, stashing message hello worker` and `Trying to identify singleton at akka.tcp://mySys@127.0.0.1:2552/user/worker/singleton` (which fails and retries) -> It is looking for the singleton on the wrong node, since no manager is available and it is apparently not aware that the singleton is on the worker node.</del>

When creating the `ClusterSingletonManager` on the worker node directly everything works as expected.

You also had an issue with your naming of the manager. Your `singletonName` is `worker` and your manager itself (the actor) does not have any name. When you create the proxy you use the path `/user/singleton/worker`, but the path should be as follows: `/user/{actorName}/{singletonName}`. So in my code I used `worker` as the actorName and `singleton` as the `singletonName`.

So here's my working code:

```
object Manager extends App {
  val sys = ActorSystem("mySys", ConfigFactory.load("application").getConfig("manager"))
  sys.actorOf(Props[Manager], "manager")
}

class Manager extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MemberUp(member) if member.address != Cluster(context.system).selfAddress =>
      context.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props(
        singletonPath = s"/user/worker/singleton",
        role = Some("worker")), name = "workerProxy") ! "hello worker"
  }
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    Cluster(context.system).subscribe(self,classOf[MemberUp])
  }
}
```

---

```
object Worker extends App{
  val sys = ActorSystem("mySys", ConfigFactory.load("application").getConfig("worker"))

  sys.actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.props(
    singletonProps = Props(classOf[Worker]),
    singletonName = "singleton",
    terminationMessage = PoisonPill,
    role = Some("worker")), name = "worker")
}

class Worker extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg =>
      println(s"GOT MSG : $msg from : ${sender().path.name}")
  }
}
```

application.conf and build.sbt stayed the same.

EDIT

Got it to work with by referencing the `ClusterSingletonProxy` with the actual path on the worker node (calculating in that it is a network path). I am not sure if I would recommend this, since I am still not sure, if that library is designed to be able to do this, but it works at least in this minimal example:

```
object Manager extends App {
  val sys = ActorSystem("mySys", ConfigFactory.load("application").getConfig("manager"))
  sys.actorOf(Props[Manager], "manager")
}

class Manager extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MemberUp(member) if member.address != Cluster(context.system).selfAddress =>
      val ref = context.system.actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.props(
        singletonProps = Props(classOf[Worker]),
        singletonName = "singleton",
        terminationMessage = PoisonPill,
        role = Some("worker")).withDeploy(Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(member.address))), name = "worker")

      context.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props(
        singletonPath = s"${ref.path.toStringWithoutAddress}/singleton", // /remote/akka.tcp/mySys@127.0.0.1:2552/user/worker/singleton
        role = Some("worker")), name = "workerProxy") ! "hello worker"
  }
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    Cluster(context.system).subscribe(self,classOf[MemberUp])
  }
}
```

---

```
object Worker extends App{
  val sys = ActorSystem("mySys", ConfigFactory.load("application").getConfig("worker"))
}

class Worker extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg =>
      println(s"GOT MSG : $msg from : ${sender().path.name}")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it did work. However it works only for 1 actor. If I try to add another manager and another worker where manager2 deploys a second singleton worker2, then starts the proxy and sends a message, the message doesn't reach worker1(which is the active singleton). It's weird that they didn't want to allow remote deployment of singletons yet they allow calling withDeploy on ClusterSingletonManager props. wonder if it is the same in newer versions.